# Parse whole file using CSV to get all validation errors together

Tags: java, opencsv

I am using OpenCSV to parse CSV files. I would like to be able to get all of the validation errors that may occur together, rather than one at a time, so that users can fix all the errors, and not have to keep resubmitting the CSV with only one change.

Is there an annotation or way of writing the validators to continue validating the whole file even if there are errors, which can be collected together later?

Comment: I'd guess that something like this isn't possible. After first encountered error rest of the file can't be parsed, recovering from it might be really complicated.

Comment: I agree with the above comment. When parsing things yourself, like "line by line"; you *might* be able to continue parsing the following lines. But this is similar to compiling source code: it is really hard to understand whether "later" errors ... are real errors, or just "follow on" problems because of that very first error.